# Insert null in date field in postgresql using collection

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I am trying to insert an array with date field - end_date in postgresql with Laravel 5.7. But this gives an error -

```
SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"end_date\" violates not-null constraint
```

I am using Laravel 5.7, Postgresql 9.3

```
$array = [
  "amazon_store_id" => 4
  "advertising_profile_id" => 1
  "campaign_id" => 123
  "name" => "6 shelf 2"
  "campaign_type" => "sponsoredProducts"
  "targeting_type" => "manual"
  "premium_bid_adjustment" => true
  "daily_budget" => 15.0
  "start_date" => "2014-11-25 09:32:18"
  "end_date" => null
  "state" => "paused"
  "serving_status" => "CAMPAIGN_PAUSED"
  "creation_date" => "2014-11-07 10:17:03"
  "last_updated_date" => "2018-10-24 12:49:54"
  "created_at" => "2018-12-24 09:32:18"
  "updated_at" => "2018-12-24 09:32:18"
];
DB::table($table_name)->insert($array->toArray());
```

Ideally it shall insert the null in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your migration you can do this to make the column nullable:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tablename', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dateTime('end_date')->nullable();
    });
}
```

**->nullable()** Designate that the column allows NULL values

Answer (score 0):

In your migration file you have to define the date field as nullable.

```
Schema::table($table_name, function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dateTime('end_date')->nullable();
});
```